# How to insert blank frames in a video using MP4 Parser?

Tags: android, mp4parser

I am using MP4 Parser library to merge multiple videos into one on Android. I was wondering whether it would be possible to add blank frames (something like black background for two seconds) to separate these videos.

I do not know the dimensions and frame rates of the videos that will be merged so I cannot simply use a two seconds black video. Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to add 10 second of black frames to the beginning of my clip and 30 seconds of black frames at end of clip. This is what I got so far.

```
ffmpeg -i XX.mp4 -vf "
color=c=black:s=720x576:d=10 [pre] ;
color=c=black:s=720x576:d=30 [post] ;
[pre] [in] [post] concat=n=3" -an -vcodec mpeg2video -pix_fmt yuv422p -s 720v576 -aspect 16:9 -r 25 -minrate 30000k -maxrate 30000k -b 30000k output.mpg
```